# Remove class from next element jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a this html:

```
<div class="results">
<div class="resultitem" page="1">
    <div class="col-sm-12 odd">
        <div class="col-sm-2 noLRPadding"><p class="memFName">Arsene</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 noLRPadding"><p class="memLName">Wenger</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 noLRPadding"><p class="memEmail">louise.lockie@wilmingtonplc.com</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 noLRPadding"><p class="memLevel">Affiliate</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 noLRPadding"><p class="memCPD">0</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 noLRPadding"><p class="memTarCPD">10</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 hidden noLRPadding"><p class="memDiff">10</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 noLRPadding"><p><a class="memLink" href="/my-membership/cpd-centre/cpd-log/?m=CON-000184210">View</a></p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 noLRPadding text-center"><a class="showConfirm" href="#" data-user="CON-000184210" data-username="Arsene Wenger"><i style="font-size: 18px; color: #b43e91" class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="logPanel hidden">
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="resultitem" page="1">
    <div class="col-sm-12 odd">
        <div class="col-sm-2 noLRPadding"><p class="memFName">Jack</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 noLRPadding"><p class="memLName">Wilshire</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 noLRPadding"><p class="memEmail">louise.lockie@wilmingtonplc.com</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 noLRPadding"><p class="memLevel">Affiliate</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 noLRPadding"><p class="memCPD">0</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 noLRPadding"><p class="memTarCPD">10</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 hidden noLRPadding"><p class="memDiff">10</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 noLRPadding"><p><a class="memLink" href="/my-membership/cpd-centre/cpd-log/?m=CON-000184209">View</a></p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1 noLRPadding text-center"><a class="showConfirm" href="#" data-user="CON-000184209" data-username="Jack Wilshire"><i style="font-size: 18px; color: #b43e91" class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="logPanel hidden">
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And what I'm trying to do is show the 'hiddden' logPanel div when the memLink link is pressed so in script I've got:

```
$(".results").on("click", ".memLink", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).nextAll('.logPanel').first().removeClass('hidden');
alert("hello");
});
```

but tweak as I might I can't get this to work. Could some =one shed any light please?

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: You can tr this: $(this).nextAll('.logPanel').removeClass('hidden');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find **closest** class "resultitem", and then find required **first element**.

```
    $(this).closest(".resultitem").find(".logPanel:first").removeClass('hidden');
```

Comment: Just not picking it up :(

Comment: Hi Sandip, yep that seems to have gotten it! :)

Comment: perfect for my needs thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$(".memLink").on("click", function (e) {
   $(this).closest(".resultitem").find('.logPanel:first').removeClass('hidden');
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time matey, sadly that's not working either

Comment: sorry, I will help you, I need to know where `.results` and `.memLink` , can you add more html elemtens to be easy for me.

Comment: I have updated js. please try that and give me feedback

Comment: Nope still not getting it sadly :(

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but `.memLink` is not near `.logPanel`. You must use something like that:

```
$(this).parent().next('.logPanel').removeClass('hidden');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.closest()`

```
$(this).closest('.noLRPadding').next().removeClass('hidden');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$(this).parents().find(".resultitem").find('.logPanel:first').removeClass('hidden');
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. If possible please explain about your answer. stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: hi sorry, actually they have changed in html code, now i have altered

Answer (score 0):

use `closest()`

```
$(".results").on("click", ".memLink", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest(".odd").next(".logPanel").removeClass("hidden");
    alert("hello");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I've had a play and managed to get what you wanted.

I've added a fiddle, here: https://jsfiddle.net/f87echp6/1/ *note, that I've removed your `a` links and just used `#` for the demo.

Here's all the jQuery you need:

```
$(".memLink").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var item = $(this).closest('.resultitem');
    var logPanel = $(item).find('.logPanel');
    $(logPanel).removeClass('hidden');
});
```

This works in the following way:

1. Handle the click of the `.memLink` element
2. `e.preventDefault();` stops the default action happening - which in this case is to open the `a`'s link
3. Find the `memLink`'s closest `resultItem` (being the parent div)
4. Find the child `logPanel` of the item
5. Remove the `hidden` class from the `logPanel` child

You could surely neaten this down into a couple of lines, but I've stepped it out, so you can see what's happening.

Happy coding!